# Parameter appears in URL only after second button click

Tags: php

I have strange problem with my search form. After I enter keyword and do the search request I get empty parameter value.

For example I type in the search field the word "something"

I see an empty value:

```
search.php?keyword=
```

After this I enter the keyword "else" and I recieve:

`search.php?keyword=something` instead of `search.php?keyword=else`

They somehow appear with "one step back"

I was trying to debug with print_r and var_dump but I only can print some values that does not explain my problem.

Am I missing something very trivial?

Here is what I have:

**My class function:**

```
public function show_search_result() {


        $this->search_keywords = strip_tags($_GET['keyword']);

        $this->_db->query("SELECT * from posts WHERE post_title LIKE '%$this->search_keywords%' OR post_content LIKE '%$this->search_keywords%' LIMIT 100");
        $this->rows_results_found = $this->_db->resultset();
    }
```

**And my form:**

```
<form action="search.php?keyword=<?php
                    if (isset($search_results->rows_results_found) && isset($_POST['search_requested'])) {
                        print strip_tags($_POST['search_keywords']);
                    }
                    ?>" method="post">
                        <input type="hidden" name="search_requested">
                        <input type="text" name="search_keywords" value="<?php
                        if (isset($search_results->rows_results_found) && isset($_POST['search_requested'])) {
                            print strip_tags($_POST['search_keywords']);
                        }
                        ?>"><input type="submit" value="Search">
                    </form>
```

Comment: your text input's name is `name="search_keywords"` when you're looking for `keyword` instead..

Comment: Also why are you mixing `GET` & `POST`? It will only ever be set on the second round (*when they've searched*) because the `POST` item has a value.

Comment: I understood the GET and POST messup I have made. I fixed it. Everything is with GET and this behaviour is gone.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <form action="" method=get>
    <input type=text id=se>
       <?php 
           if($_GET != null){
              $sekw = $_GET ['se'];
              $sql = //the query like='$sekw' limit=100;
       ?>
 <input type=submit>
 </form>
```

A simple code.

Your problem is when you send the form, it does save the keywords until the second send.

Comment: You need to improve on this answer, it is beyond low quality.

Comment: Yeah, sorry I'm at phone.

Comment: @wwwanaya _I'm at phone_? Seriously? This is the internet, it doesn't need real-time interaction. Noone cares if you are on the phone, just finish the call and write a useful answer afterwards. Or did someone force you to write an answer during your call?!

Comment: I'm at the phone App is, not in a call.

Answer (score 0):

change your method from post to get. also i would advice you to use a framework for easy and fast coding. some include symfony2, laravel